# FakeItEasy in C# on a servicereference

Tags: service-reference, fakeiteasy

I have a servicereference with a method I need to use in a test.

The servicereference class is defined as:

```cs
public class MyServiceReference : Clientbase<IMyServiceReference>, IMyServiceReference 
{
   public MyServiceReference()
   {
   }

    ..... methods is then defined
}
```

From my testmethod I have tried both

```cs
private MyServiceReference myServiceReferenceFake = A.Fake<MyServiceReference>();
// And
private MyServiceReference myServiceReference = new MyServiceReference();
```

For both of these is crashes in the constructor with the message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract.
```

All I need is to have a callto definition from a method in that class.
How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no experience with `Clientbase`, which I assume to be a [`System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0),but I can make some general comments.

Since you tried first to fake a `MyServiceReference`, I'll assume that you're not testing that class, and you want to use it as a collaborator for the system under test. In that case, your best bet is to try faking `IMyServiceReference`. interfaces are very easy to fake, since they don't bring along any behaviour or baggage like faking a class does.

If you feel you really need to fake a `MyServiceReference`, then we have to contend with the fact that `FakeItEasy` will eventually call `MyServiceReference()`, which will call  `ClientBase<IMyServiceReference>()`, whose [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#system-servicemodel-clientbase-1-ctor) says

> Initializes a new instance of the `ClientBase<TChannel>` class using the default target endpoint from the application configuration file.

Based on the error you reported, I assume that the application configuration file is not found or does not include the configuration required to create a `MyServiceReference`. The fact that you get the same error when you just try to instantiate a `MyServiceReference` directly strengthens my belief.

So I think your paths forward are either to try faking `IMyServiceReference` or to provide the configuration that `ClientBase<IMyServiceReference>` needs.